# TreeView duplicating root nodes, despite there being a single root in Nodes array

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently using TreeView to display a file tree for visualising diffs for a source control project. I have a "Diff" method that recursively edits an existing node in the root "Nodes" array in the TreeView, and then updates the tree afterward.

However, I've encountered an issue where the root node will duplicate for seemingly no reason, despite the debugger telling me there's a single element in the "Nodes" array at the very root of the TreeView, with no indication of an error.

I've already attempted to use "`Nodes.Clear()`" and then re-add the offending node, however even when clearing the array, the duplicate persists, (even when `Nodes.Count` is 0). I've also tried using `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()`, but to no avail.

Here's an MCVE:

```
public partial class BrokenControl : TreeView
{
   public BrokenControl()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   public void Go(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Nodes.Add("Root");
       Nodes[0] = RecursiveEdit(Nodes[0]);
       Update();
   }

   //This function simply recursively edits the Nodes array.
   int iterations = 10;
   private TreeNode RecursiveEdit(TreeNode node)
   {
      node.Nodes.Add(iterations.ToString());
      iterations--;
      if (iterations<=0)
      {
          return node;
      }

      RecursiveEdit(node.Nodes[0]);
      return node;
   }
}
```

As mentioned, I only expect there to be a single node on the TreeView when it's updated, but instead I get a duplicate node containing duplicated contents of the first.

Comment: This is a debugging problem [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017)

Comment: This is a UserControl with type TreeView, "Nodes" is a default property of the class, not my own variable. Apologies for the lack of explanation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Put a breakpoint on lines containing the text `Nodes.Add` (**all** of them). Run the code. How many times (in total) do those breakpoints get hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by using a workaround: instead of directly manipulating the Root node, saving a copy and editing, then clearing and readding, solved my issue.

Still do not know what was causing the dupe even when `Nodes.Count` was 0 and 1, however this seems to work.

Corrected MCVE:

```
public partial class BrokenControl : TreeView
{
   ...

   public void Go(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Nodes.Add("Root");
       TreeNode savedNode = RecursiveEdit(Nodes[0]);

       //This fixes it.
       Nodes.Clear();
       Nodes.Add(savedNode);

       Update();
   }

   ...
}
```